# no constructor could take the source type

Tags: c++, hashmap, overloading

I keep getting the error no constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution.

At the beginning of my code i have declared an unordered map.

```
unordered_map<char * , a_dictionary * > Mymap;


    unsigned char hash[20];
    char hex_str[41];
    string answer, line;
    int yes=0;
    cout<<"Press 1 if you would like to use the default file(d8.txt) or press 2 if you want your own file"<<endl;
    getline(cin,answer);
    stringstream(answer)>> yes;

    if(yes == 1 )
    {
        ifstream myfile("d8.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while ( myfile.good() )
            {
                getline (myfile,line);
                //cout<<line<<endl;
                a_dictionary * dic = new dictionary();
                dic->word = line;

                const char * c= line.c_str();
                sha1::calc(c,line.length(), hash);
                sha1::toHexString(hash,hex_str);
                Mymap.insert(hex_str, dic); //
```

THis line right here "mymap.insert" keeps giving me the error  error C2664: 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist> std::_Hash<_Traits>::insert(std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>,_Valty) even though im passing the right values right?

here is the function that call toHeXString

```
void toHexString(const unsigned char* hash, char* hexstring)
{
    const char hexDigits[] = { "0123456789abcdef" };

    for (int hashByte = 20; --hashByte >= 0;)
    {
        hexstring[hashByte << 1] = hexDigits[(hash[hashByte] >> 4) & 0xf];
        hexstring[(hashByte << 1) + 1] = hexDigits[hash[hashByte] & 0xf];
    }
    hexstring[40] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert it as a pair.

```
Mymap.insert(std::make_pair(hex_str, dic));
```

Or use C++11 Initializer lists

```
Mymap.insert({hex_str, dic});
```

Check out examples [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/)

Alternatively you could use [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at), yielding cleaner code

```
Mymap[hex_str] = dic;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/
check the declaration of insert. You want std::pair.